# How to echo the right variable in this array

Tags: php, arrays

print_r gives:

```
Array ( 
  [8a19c684f653ac779ae1af5340d482bf] => Array ( 
    [booking] => Array ( 
      [_year] => 2016  
      [_month] => 2  
      [_day] => 27  
      [_persons] => Array ( [0] => 1 )  
      [_date] => 2016-2-27  
      [date] => February 27, 2016  
      [_time] =>  
      [_qty] => 1  
      [Persons] => 1  
      [_start_date] => 1456531200  
      [_end_date] => 1456617599  
      [_all_day] => 1  
      [_cost] => 36.2  
      [_booking_id] => 175  
    )   
    [product_id] => 145   
    [variation_id] => 0   
    [variation] => Array ( )   
    [quantity] => 1   
    [line_total] => 21   
    [line_tax] => 0   
    [line_subtotal] => 36.2   
    [line_subtotal_tax] => 0   
    [line_tax_data] => Array (   
      [total] => Array ( ) 
      [subtotal] => Array ( )   
    )   
    [data] => WC_Product_Booking Object (   
      [availability_rules:WC_Product_Booking:private] => Array ( )   
      [id] => 145 
      [post] => WP_Post Object (  
        [ID] => 145   
        [post_author] => 1   
        [post_date] => 2015-12-29 18:08:32   
        [post_date_gmt] => 2015-12-29 18:08:32   
        [post_content] => Sensational comedy   
        [post_title] => Bournemouth   
        [post_excerpt] =>   
        [post_status] => publish   
        [comment_status] => closed   
        [ping_status] => closed   
        [post_password] =>   
        [post_name] => bournemouth   
        [to_ping] =>   
        [pinged] =>   
        [post_modified] => 2015-12-30 19:26:20   
        [post_modified_gmt] => 2015-12-30 19:26:20   
        [post_content_filtered] =>   
        [post_parent] => 0   
        [guid] => /product/bournemouth/   
        [menu_order] => 0   
        [post_type] => product   
        [post_mime_type] =>   
        [comment_count] => 0   
        [filter] => raw   
      )   
      [product_type] => booking   
      [shipping_class:protected] =>    
      [shipping_class_id:protected] => 0    
      [price] => 36.2    
      [manage_stock] => no    
      [stock_status] => instock    
      [tax_status] => taxable    
    )   
  ) 
)
```

How do I echo _start_date ?

I already know that the following code will echo post_title

```
foreach($items as $item => $values) { 
    $_product = $values['data']->post; 
    echo $_product->post_title;
}
```

Comment: do you mean `variable` or `object`?

Comment: your print_r is really confusing, can you run a var_dump and post a image?

Comment: Just put a `echo "<pre>"; print_r($array);` in your code and post the output here.

Comment: inside of your `foreach` you can access to it by `echo $value['booking']['_start_date']`

Answer (score 0):

```
print $_product->post_title['8a19c684f653ac779ae1af5340d482bf']['booking']['_start_date'];
```

but try

```
function showStruc(&$array,$prefix='$array'){
   foreach($array as $k=>$v){
      echo ($k = $prefix."['$k']"), "<br>";
      if(is_array($v)){
          showStruc($v,$k);
      }
   }
}
showStruc($array);
```

to see the full structure
(sorry for posting an infiniti loop, now it works)

Answer (score 0):

This associative array has just one item. If you expect to have more than one item on the collection then the foreach is needed and you can **try this code**:

```
 // iterate over the array items (booking, product_id, variation etc)
 foreach($items as $item => $values) { 

      // get the values associated with the items 
      $elem = $values['_start_date']; 

      // if the variable $values has an element  called _start_date
      // will print it
      echo $elem;
}
```

That previuos code is not completely ok. Because it try to look for a _start_date variable on every value associated with an item on the array.
Just prints once because there is no other value for the items on the array with the field _start_date

Otherwise if just is one item on the array **try with**:

```
echo($arr[0]->booking->_start_date);
```

Answer (score -1):

ty smoqadam

that was simpler than i had thought

```
foreach($items as $item => $values) { 
    echo $values['booking']['_start_date'];
}
```